# How to make a URL for pages in my site that looks like this: http://www.example.com/username?

Tags: php, mysql, html, url

I'm building some kind of social-network site using PHP and mysql (and quite new to web development..). I want user profiles to be accessible trough the URL address as "http://www.example.com/username". 
It is also very important to me that each profile page will be indexed by search engines.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [.htaccess](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/htaccess.html) - [mod_rewrite](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=mode+rewrite+example) to be more specific

You can find many resources online for this.